# How to replace an actual "\n" string, not the line break escape

Tags: c#, winforms, replace

I've been trying for the last two hours, but i can't replace the string **\n**, this is what i did:

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.ASCII;
for (int i = 0; i < numpntr; i++)
{
    bw.BaseStream.Position = strt + i*var;
    bw.Write(
        enc.GetBytes(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text.Replace("\n","\x0A") + (new string('\0',
            bytecnt - enc.GetByteCount(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text.Replace("\n" + "\x0A"))))));
}
bw.Flush();
bw.Close();
bw = null;
```

is there anyway to replace it as a string ?

Comment: Maybe escape it? `\\n` instead of `\n`?

Comment: Thank you for that, please post it as an answer please :D

Comment: I felt I had to downvote I'm afraid, you could've google'd this and found your answer quite easily.

Comment: @DeeMac: No hard feelings my friend, but i did google and didn't find any, i even searched here but nothing about an actual **\n**, only about the break line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use  `" \\n "` or you can put `' @ '` begining of your string like this:

```
enc.GetBytes(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text.Replace(@"\n" + "\x0A")
```

They are called **verbatim strings**, you can take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) documentation.

Comment: +1, thank you for your answer but @Tim has already answered me.

Comment: I see, I just wanted give you another alternative

Comment: it was actually a nice one too, if he doesn't post an answer i'll check yours as the answer.